# Windows 7 x32 или Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows

Здраствуйте . Я планирую покупать , процессор Intel Core i7 3820 . И хотел бы узнать какую версию Windows 7 ставить (32 или 64) ? **Нужен совет именно программистов** , поскольку программы которые я буду тестировать под 64 , будут ли корректно работать на Windows x32 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Однозначно ставьте ОС 64-бит.

На ней поставьте Oracle VM VirtualBox (или другой пакет виртуализации). Это позволит иметь как 32-бит, так и 64-бит **виртуальные мащины**. На них можете ставить любой виндоус, линукс и т.д., объединять их в LAN и гонять любой (почти) софт.

Comment: вы правы, с таким железом как у него проблем не будет с производительностью.

Answer (score 2):

программы написанные под архитектуру 64 бит, не будут корректно работать на железе 32 бит

Comment: @savro x64 будет заметно производительнее ? Как вы поступаете ?

Comment: я слава богу еще не сталкивался с надобностью 64 бит, по этому вин7 32 и пишу под 32.
под 64 мои программы работают на ура, но программы под 64 бит, на машине 32 бит работать не будут.
по этому если у Вас задача состоит в тестировании софта который написан под 64 то у Вас только один вариант, ставить систему 64 битную.

Answer (score 1):

Сперва скажите, на каком ЯП вы будете писать программы! Далее, если у вас будет установлено более 3 гб оперативной памяти, то ставьте 64 чтоб использовать ваш компьютер на полную (да с і7 процессором ставьте 64 без вопросов)... 
Да, 64 заметно быстрее работает чем 32 (если хотите максимальной скорости работы,  ставьте Windows 8 64 - работает раза в три быстрее чем 7)
И по поводу "будут ли идти программы 64 по 32 и наоборот" - все зависит от того,  как написана программа.

Comment: по вопросу видно что человек писать не собирается, он будет тестировать кем то писанное ПО. и ПО это будет писано под 64, так что ставить однозначно ему нужно 64.

Comment: да, я тоже так считаю особенно с таким производительным процессором.

Comment: @savro @Mr-kto я пишу на C# , ОЗУ - 16Gb . Раньше у меня было среднее железо и vista x32 , такими вопросами не задавался.

Comment: И сколько на висте х32 показывалось из 16 Гб ?
по архитектуре х32 толку от более 3,75 Гб нету.

Comment: @savro ))) Сейчас vista и 2Gb DDR2 . В понедельник будет i7 и 16Gb DDR3

Comment: вы пишете игры на unity 3d + C# для того вам аж 16Гб ОЗУ?

Comment: Autocad + C# , да и просто по 10-12 программ открыто

Comment: Почти угадал) при компиляции программ можно выбирать для каких платформ 64, 32, любая платформа (так в VS в других IDE незнаю)

Comment: @Mr-kto значит я могу спокойно ставить x64 и в VS 2012 (когда она выйдет) выбирать между 32 и 64 ?

Comment: да, VS2012 уже вышло!

Answer (score 0):

Если ты пишешь на VisualStudio то она 32 битная и программы написанные на ней будут отлично работать на 32 битной архитектуре.

Comment: Архитектура IDE не связана с архитектурой создаваемых приложений.